Trackpad Stopped Working on Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1 Gen 12 with Ubuntu 24.04
Hello Ubuntu Community,
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1 Gen 12.I'm facing an issue with the trackpad not working. I selected the full installation during the setup, the system seems to have install the necessary drivers for the trackpad as It worked for two sessions after that it suddenly stopped working.I was able to see trackpad setting in 'Setting'.
Here's what I have tried so far:

System Update:

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade


Installed Synaptics and Libinput Drivers:

sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-libinput


Checked Touchpad Settings:
Verified that the touchpad is not enabled in Settings > Mouse & Touchpad. Only setting for mouse are enabled.

Modified GRUB Configuration:
Edited /etc/default/grub to include:


GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux i8042.reset"

Updated GRUB and rebooted:
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot

Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue. The trackpad still does not respond.
System Information:

Model: Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1 Gen 12
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-35-generic

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any additional suggestions on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

After some time, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and it worked just fine, no issues so far.

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04; the touchpad kind of worked, but the gesture features were broken. The solution referenced here: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/1cm5up8/thinkpad_z13_gen_2_touchpad_not_working_on_ubuntu/ worked for me:
sudo rmmod i2c_hid_acpi && sudo modprobe i2c_hid_acpi

